# Ruby if .. elsIf .. else on a single line?

Tags: ruby, logic

With the ruby ternary operator we can write the following logic for a simple if else construct:

```
a = true  ? 'a' : 'b' #=> "a"
```

But what if I wanted to write this as `if foo 'a' elsif bar 'b' else 'c'`?

I could write it as the following, but it's a little difficult to follow:

```
foo = true
a = foo  ? 'a' : (bar ? 'b' : 'c') #=> "a"

foo = false
bar = true
a = foo  ? 'a' : (bar ? 'b' : 'c') #=> "b"
```

Are there any better options for handling such a scenario or is this our best bet if we wish to condense if..elsif..else logic into a single line?

Comment: I think the problem with the lack of readability in the nested ternary solution is that putting all of this on one line is inherently difficult to read, and none of the solutions you come up with are going to be much easier to parse.

Comment: In other words, with more experience you will learn that squeezing as much code into as small a space as possible is never a valid goal.

Comment: "squeezing as much code into as small a space as possible is never a valid goal." except in machine-code.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
a = (foo && "a" or bar && "b" or "c")
```

or

```
a = ("a" if foo) || ("b" if bar) || "c"
```

Comment: Interest answer, Sawa. Is this using `or` precedence as a trick?

Comment: `or` and `and` have lower associativity than `&&` and `||`.

Comment: I love this...`and` and `or` are friends as long as you learn precedence, which everyone should.

Comment: This won't work if the value you want to return is falsey. `irb(main):001:0> a = (false if true) || ("b" if true)
=> "b"`

Answer (score 21):

The [Github Ruby Styleguide](https://github.com/styleguide/ruby) recommends that one liners be reserved for trivial if/else statements and that nested ternary operators be avoided. You could use the `then` keyword but its considered bad practice.

```
if foo then 'a' elsif bar then 'b' else 'c' end
```

You could use cases (ruby's switch operator) if find your control statements overly complex.

Comment: `if foo then 'a' elsif bar then 'b' else 'c'`
No need for the semi colon after bar

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, editting to remove it now

Comment: I forgot `end` after `c`. We need to add that too.

Answer (score 6):

`a = if foo then 'a' elsif bar then 'b' else 'c' end`

Answer (score 3):

You can also write:

```
x = if foo then 'a' elsif bar then 'b' else 'c' end
```

However, this isn't idiomatic formatting in Ruby.